# A sequence of functions such that..

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I am wondering if one can find a sequence of functions $f_{n}(x)$ such that uniformly in  $n$, we have $f_n (x) \in L^1(\mathbb R)$ and $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n (x)=1$ and $ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\Vert f_n \Vert_{L^{1}}=1$ or equal to another finite constante $C>0$.

Thanks.

Comment: @John $\mathbb R$

Comment: Do you mean $n \to \infty$ instead of $n \to 0$?

Comment: @RobertIsrael  yes !! sorry

Comment: If it's going pointwise or a.s. to 1 over all of $\mathbb{R}$, why would you think the limit of the norms would be finite?

Comment: @Batman Just a guess with a Gaussian function, probably the limit could be infinite to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Fatou's lemma, if $\lim_{n \to \infty} |f_n(x)| = 1$ almost everywhere then 
$$ \lim \inf_{n \to \infty} \|f_n \|_1 \ge \int_{\mathbb R} 1\; dx = \infty $$

Comment: Thanks  for your nice answer !